# presentviewcontroller by tapping on local notification on any view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uilocalnotification

i have a xib file associated with UIViewController (someViewController.m). in my application there is a navigation controller having 6 view controllers. now i want to implement local notifications and on tapping notification, i want to show someViewController on any view that was shown when application enters inactive or background state by pressing home button.how can i do this optimally. 
 i also add observers applicationwillenterforegorundnotification in every class

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(comingfromNotification) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

-(void)comingfromNotification:(NSNotification *) notification{

RNASharedialogViewController *rsd=[[RNASharedialogViewController alloc]init];
rsd.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
rsd.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self presentViewController:rsd animated:YES completion:nil];
rsd.view.frame=CGRectMake(15.0, 10.0, 292.0, 454.0);
```

}

is this a proper way ?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround you have implemented is ok I think. I did these type of works like yours. But one thing, I must mention that if your application is navigation controlled or tab bar controlled you should present the view based on the root controller.
For example:

```
     [self.navigationController presentViewController:rsd animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: when i present viewcontroller, background becomes black. and i am changing the frame of viewcontroller after presenting it , but it doesnot changing its size.

Comment: try this [self presentViewController:rsd animated:YES completion:{
rsd.view.frame=CGRectMake(15.0, 10.0, 292.0, 454.0); }];

Comment: view mode was scale to fill. i changed it to center. Done